# React Native Firebase Presence Idle

Tags: firebase, react-native, user-presence, idle-timer

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html?m=1

In this blog, I can see idle is added through script, how can we add idle in order to listen the statuses (`onIdle`, `onAway` & `onBack`) in react native?

Comment: The Firebase client does its own connection management, and the blog post uses that to build a presence system The exact same approach works in React Native, although I recommend having a look at the (more up to date) documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state. If you're having trouble making this work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah I implemented the other things, but the question is for the IDLE listeners... How would you add the script in React Native, they added for web?